# Using json datasource with JasperReports 4.5.1. Get JRExpressionEvalException exception

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm having issues accessing the array from my JSON data source. I'm using *jasperreports 4.5.1*.

My contact.json file:

```
{ "Person": { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith", "Contacts": [ { "Type":
"Cell", "Number": "555-555-5555" }, { "Type": "Home", "Number": "666-666-6666" }
] }
}
```

My contact.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="contact" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<subDataset name="Contactdataset">
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Type" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Type"/>
    </field>
    <field name="Number" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Number"/>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.FirstName"/>
</field>
<field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.LastName"/>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="300" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[First Name:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="80" height="30"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Last Name:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="200" height="30"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FirstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="80" y="30" width="200" height="30"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="130" y="166" width="150" height="23"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Contactdataset">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Person.Contacts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="23" width="150">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="27" y="0" width="100" height="17"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Type}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="157" y="150" width="100" height="16"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```

I also tried passing `Contactdataset` as :

```
<queryString language="json"> 
<![CDATA[Person.Contacts]]> 
</queryString>
```

and passed that in the `datasourceexpression` like:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Contactdataset")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

What I am doing wrong? I'm getting the following error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>    Source text :
>   ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Person.Contacts")

Answer (score 0):

In JasperReports 4.5.1 there was no `subDataSource()` method for the [`JsonDataSource`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/jr-4-5-1/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JsonDataSource.java). It was introduced in JasperReports 5.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Narcis, the `subDataSource()` method for the JsonDataSource was introduced in JasperReports 5.0.4. and with this fact, you cannot use it in   ***jasperreports 4.5.1.*** You should then try creating Main report and a Subreport. Add the field `FirstName` & `LastName` in the detail band of Main report and create a Subreport to iterate over the `Contacts` data. Add this Subreport on the detail band of Main report, select SubReport Poperties: **"Use a datasource expression"** and set below value for the datasource expression:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream($F{Contacts}.toString().getBytes()),"")
```

In your Subreport, add `Type` & `Number` field and it would print the nested array accordingly, for every node of the main array.

Comment: Thank you Sourav and Narcis, So basically if I upgrade to 5.0.4 or higher, my template as the original post would work as is or would I still have to go subReport way?

Comment: @fogo: Your current template should work fine  with upgraded version of jasperreports.